# Is it possible to use association like active record when using sitemap generator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to use the gem called   [sitemap_generator](https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator)

Then I've done with setup then I coded like this below

**sitemap.rb**

```
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do

  Code.find_each do |f|
    add "/community/#{f.community.community_name}/code/#{f.id}", :lastmod => f.updated_at
  end

end
```

But I get this error if I run `rake sitemap:refresh`

**Error**

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `community_name' for nil:NilClass
```

Am I not supposed to be able to use nested association within this?
If possible, how can I?

By the way, `Code` belongs to `Community`, and `Community` has many `Codes`
It's already defined in model, and working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sitemap_generator I do nested resources like this

```
Community.find_each do |community|
  add community_path(community), :lastmod => f.updated_at
  community.codes.find_each do |code|
    add code_path(code), :lastmod => f.updated_at
  end
end
```

This will provide a map of /communities/1 and also a map of communities/1/codes/1